# WebSphere 8.5 disables CDI when different JSF version is used

Tags: websphere, cdi, jsf-2.2

I'm using Websphere 8.5 with JSF 2.2 (mojarra).
A different JSF-Version is disabling the CDI-Support ([see here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7e0a2aae-f0be-4e4f-87ba-37c84c4db9a7&ps=25) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/cweb_cdi_integration.html)).
This seems common with every Java EE Server, and i found a way to activate CDI with something called a [cdi-enabler](http://www.manorrock.com/blog/2013/12/10/jsf_tip_54_enable_cdi_when_bundling_jsf.html). With the cdi-enabler CDI works even with a differnent JSF Version.

My Questions:

1. Why is CDI disabled, when a different JSF-Version is used?
2. How "save" is it to use the cdi-enabler? (maybe there was a good reason
   to disable CDI support)?

Comment: I didn't think it disabled CDI completely, I just thought that the third party JSF implementation didn't integrate with the CDI container.

Answer (score 1):

CDI and JSF require integration to work together.  WebSphere Application Server integrates its builtin CDI and JSF implementations.  It does not "disable" CDI with your custom JSF per se, but rather when you provide your own JSF there is no integration.

I have no experience with cdi-enabler, so I don't know how complete the integration will be.